# Android: how to simply draw a bitmap on another bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

I'm new to Android dev and I'm having a hard time trying to do something which seems obvious to me: drawing little images on top of a bigger image.

Let's say that I have a 500x500 image and I want to draw icons at different locations. Icons are png files that I load with:

> Bitmap img =
>   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
>   R.drawable.idIcon1)

My "background image" is a LayerDrawable.

Then, I am totally lost... Do I have to create a canvas ? How to draw on my "background image" my icons at different positions?

Comment: use this:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540272/android-how-to-overlay-a-bitmap-draw-over-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 5):

```
int positionLeft=0;
int positionTop=0;
Bitmap newBitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, positionLeft, positionTop,null);
positionLeft=100;
positionTop=100;         
canvas.drawBitmap(iconBitmap,positionLeft,positionTop,null);
imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making simple things difficult. Just use a layout with `android:background` attribute, and then add `ImageView`s dynamically with the necessary bitmaps inside.

Comment: In my case the "background" isn't the background of my View.

Comment: @Vladimir, And there are other applications like adding a video player icon to a thumbnail bitmap.

Comment: He wants to draw stuff. Don't assume anything like he wants to create a simple view with images. I came here because I need to draw stuff and not create views.