# Android, How to add a bitmap layer over another bitmap layer, dynamically from list?

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, overlay, bit-manipulation

In my application, I have a list adapter. each row includes an imageView in left and two textViews in right. For getting images I'm using [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library.

my getView() method is this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;        

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView     = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_news_adapter, null);
            holder          = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivIcon   = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_news_icon);
            holder.tvTitle  = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_news_title);
            holder.tvDate   = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_news_date);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.tvTitle.setText(video.getTitle().get(position));
        holder.tvDate.setText(localTime.get(position));

        // Load and display image
        String imageUrl = (video.getDefaultImage128x96().get(position));
        imageUrl = imageUrl.trim().replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, holder.ivIcon, options);



        holder.ivIcon.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap image = holder.ivIcon.getDrawingCache();
        if(image != null) {
            image = putOverlay(image, holder.ivIcon.getWidth(), holder.ivIcon.getHeight());
            holder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(image);
            holder.ivIcon.destroyDrawingCache();
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

in following code, I'm giving list of URLs to that libray to be downloaded in different threads.

```
// Load and display image
String imageUrl = (video.getDefaultImage128x96().get(position));
imageUrl = imageUrl.trim().replaceAll(" ", "%20");
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, holder.ivIcon, options);
```

after that in following code, i'm getting current image of imageView (which is downloaded) and ask other method to add a layer on top of this image.

```
holder.ivIcon.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image = holder.ivIcon.getDrawingCache();

if(image != null) {
        image = putOverlay(image, holder.ivIcon.getWidth(), holder.ivIcon.getHeight());
        holder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(image);
        holder.ivIcon.destroyDrawingCache();
}
```

putOverlay() method is like this:

```
public Bitmap putOverlay(Bitmap bmp, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap overLay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.video_overlay);

        Bitmap bmBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmBackground);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint); 
        canvas.drawBitmap(overLay, width*3/8, height*3/8, paint);

        return bmBackground;
    }
```

It was functional part. What about result!
Universal Image Loader library uses predefined image as long as main image is under downloading. my code can merge this two layers.
[image]

However, when main image is downloaded it overrides previous image while i expect my overlay image sits on top of this image.
[image]

But, after scroll of screen, i can see my added image (most of images has and some of them doesn't have my added image).
[image]

any suggestion/comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was easier than the thing that i was thinking.

First I removed those

```
holder.ivIcon.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image = holder.ivIcon.getDrawingCache();
if(image != null) {
    image = putOverlay(image, holder.ivIcon.getWidth(), holder.ivIcon.getHeight());
    holder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(image);
    holder.ivIcon.destroyDrawingCache();
}
```

and `putOverlay()` method from my list adapter and then in XML file of row (`list_news_adapter`), I added another imageView and set its  source attribute with my image.

Wow, it works fine.