# how do i move an image view placed over other image view in android?

Tags: android

I have 1 image view  as a background which is chosen from a gallery of small thumbnails and I place a second image view on it at run time how can I move it anywhere over the existing image view and save it, both together?

Comment: check similar answers 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540272/android-how-to-overlay-a-bitmap-draw-over-a-bitmap