# Canvas Drawing using an image as place holder

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to have a drawing canvas within my application which will display letter to free draw for practice. Something like the following:

[image]

**OR**

[image]

This is the first time I will be implementing this method so a few questions.

- Can I have my own background for the canvas? (let's say a chalkboard?)
- Do I have to create the letter as image and insert it onto the canvas as Bitmap?

I saw some tutorials but wasn't too clear on how to implement it within app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would have to use 2 different Canvas'. One for holding the Background Image (Bitmap), and the other overlaying the background Canvas where you can do your work.

Comment: @MattMatt Thanks. Any idea on how to implement? Or any good tutorials?

Comment: I added an answer for you. If it helps and is what you're looking for, Accept so this can be considered "Answered". Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for you. Having more than 1 `Canvas` is not the answer (Although may work, I'm still new), but instead draw a seperate `Bitmap` *on top of* the first `Bitmap` (background).

Try this out for size: [Overlying Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540272/android-how-to-overlay-a-bitmap-draw-over-a-bitmap)

You should then be able to edit the overlaying `Bitmap` without affecting the original `Bitmap`.

Cheers!

Comment: Would I create the entire thing in my on create () method?

Comment: You can initialize the Bitmaps in your onCreate(), but keep in mind that it can be heavy on the UI Thread, causing lag and possibly "App Not Responding". I would look here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html to preserve the responsiveness of your application's UI. The actual drawing will be done in your onDraw() method.