# How do I make a balloon shaped ImageView?

Tags: android, bitmap, shapes

I was tring to make a ImageView that follows a shape of another ImageView's source, or even its own background. I want something like this:

[image]

> But I'm getting this:
>
> [image]
>
> When I try this:
>
> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/mimage"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:maxHeight="80dp"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_conteudo_balao"
>     android:background="@mipmap/pomba"
>     android:maxWidth="80dp"/>
> ```
>
> Or this:
>
> [image]
>
> When I try this:
>
> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/mimage"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:maxHeight="80dp"
>     android:src="@mipmap/pomba"
>     android:background="@drawable/ic_chat_conteudo_balao"
>     android:maxWidth="80dp"/>
> ```

I've also tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2287218/2938090) answer, but it was not what I want:

[image]

Well, I don't know what to do anymore. Is there a way to put a bitmap inside another bitmap following its shape?

Here are the images I'm working on

[image] [image]

I think this is not a duplicate because I am working with 9-patch, it's a little bit different as karaokyo said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Masking(crop) image in frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a little bit different if you use a 9-patch mask.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mimage);

NinePatchDrawable mask = (NinePatchDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.balloon);
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pomba);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
mask.getPaint().setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
mask.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight()));
mask.draw(canvas);

imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
```