# Google Maps Static API: Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to send a `GET` request to

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=***&center=443.665751,-79.403373&zoom=12&size=800x600&path=color:0xFF0000AA|weight:1|fillcolor:0xFFB6C1BB|enc:...
```

which the entire URL size is `272532` bytes. But when I send this request, I get `Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)` error with this message:

```
Your client issued a request that was too large.
```

Is there any way to send large requests (when the `path` parameter is very long) to Google Maps Static API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Encoded Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) as `path` parameter in [URL request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#URL_Parameters). You can encode polyline via [`encode()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/latest/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html) method of `PolyUtil` class of [Maps SDK Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility#poly-encoding). Also you can reduce number of points in path via [`simplify()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/latest/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html) method of `PolyUtil` class (it implements [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)). So "maximum compression" for `path` is:

1. reduce number of points in path using [`simplify()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/latest/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html);
2. reduce length of `path` parameter of URL request using [`encode()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/latest/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html).

Also, you can create several requests with path parts and "merge" response images (as bitmaps) to create full path (e.g. [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1540272/6950238)).

Comment: The Javascript API has encoding capabilities via the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#encoding).

Comment: @MrUpsidown You are right. Also both algorithms can be implemented manually.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't get why you linked to the Android SDK since the question didn't mention  Android but the JS API tag.

Comment: @MrUpsidown It's just because probably initially the questions was tagged by `[android]` tag. But seems answer can be applied in any platform.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I am already using the encode method as you can see the `enc:` parameter in `path`, but still the request is so large that Google doesn't allow it. Also I tried the `simplify` method as well but it didn't reduce the points much and I still have the original problem!

Comment: @hhhal So use p.3: split request to several parts and merge bitmaps.